# how to set Onclick listner for footer layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a footer.xml layout and I'm using it on most activities in my app. The problem is that it has some buttons. How can I implement a click listener for them, and use it everywhere?

Comment: put code where footer was inflated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Inflact` layout in your Activity. and then can perform Action on view of that layout.

**Try this**

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view= inflator.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_FOOTER_LAYOUT, null);

Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform action
        }
    });
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. you can check that green tick mark if you feel this is correct answer ;)

Comment: sorry but my problem is'nt solve yet, Actually,i am trying to inflate footer.xml from non activity class.

Comment: footer for list view or gridview?